# where in the first quadrant does the rose r = sin(3θ) have a vertical tangent

Tags: calculus

I tried to solve the question but got no vertical tangent. however, the correct answer is θ = 0.47. I am not sure what I did wrong, any help is appreciated.

here is my work:

$$\frac{dx}{dθ} = r'\cos\theta - r\sin\theta$$

$$r' = 3\cos3θ$$

$$\frac{dx}{dθ} = 3\cos3θ\cosθ - \sin3θ\sinθ$$

$$0 = 3\cos3θ\cosθ - \sin3θ\sinθ $$

I used the graphing method and resulted in no solution

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Your method is correct so far: can you continue?

Comment: Also, I haven't heard of the term "rose" before...can someone please explain what that is{ with respect to the question, ofc :)}

Comment: It's a polar graph with 'petals'.

Comment: @TobyMak ohhhhhh makes sense, thank you!

Comment: Are you allowed your graphics calculator for this? If you need an approximate answer only, just graph the function and then click 'analyse graph' -> 'roots'.

Comment: ah alright, I really appreciate it, thank you!

Comment: @SmritiSivakumar see https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/rosace/rosace.shtml

Comment: @user3733558 thank you for the reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is correct. Continuing gives:

$$3 \cos 3 \theta \cos \theta -  \sin 3 \theta \sin \theta = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow 2 \cos 3 \theta \cos \theta - 2 \sin 3\theta \sin \theta + \cos 3 \theta \cos \theta + \sin 3 \theta \sin \theta  = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow 2 \cos 4\theta + \cos 2\theta=0$$

and after substituting $u = 2 \theta$, you have:

$$2(2 \cos^2 u - 1) + \cos u = 0$$

which is a quadratic in $\cos u$.

Comment: Ohhh I see, thank you!

Comment: No problem! Hope this helped.

Comment: @ari If this answer helped you, you may want to accept the answer. Please see how to accept an answer. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer/3287#3287